is it possible to create a simple dummy apk to replace an app that causes trouble?
is it possible to create a simple dummy apk to replace an app that causes trouble? The apk would just do nothing.
my goal is to prevent the unnecessary app from bloating the small ram j7 has.
The app to be replaced is: google play services (i dont care losing its functionalities...), because on j7 we cant: disable it, uninstall it, not even using adb shell as it says permission denied or the app is device admin (there is no command to remove admin from app thru adb shell on dpm help)...
rooting is not an option. It will force a bootloader unlocked that will prevent netflix working properly.
so my last hope is ask them to let I didable or uninstall it (already lost this hope just after thinking it),
or find another workaround to solve the ram bloating problem.
so i thought that one way could be to dummify these problematic apps. And uninstall everything that depends on it too of course. But is it possible? How can it be done?

"Replacing a system app" on a non-rooted device is only possible is you have access to the private signature key the app has been signed with. If you would have this you could install your ap as an update.
For Play Services only Google has the private key, therefore this is not possible.
Anyway you seem to underestimate the importance of Google Play Services. Even if this system app has no direct visible functionality it is crucial for many apps as it is used as some sort of library by other apps, e.g. for checking if the app has a valid Google Play License (was bought in Play Store). Also all Google Push functionality of all apps is implemented in Play Services.
Your device Samsung Galaxy J7 was released in 2015 with 1.5GB RAM - all apps have grown in size and RAM usage a lot in those 9 years. If you want to get rid of Play Services you can try to find a Google free custom ROM that replaces your current stock ROM or consider switching to a newer phone model.

I will probably install lineageOS soon. I didnt want to completely get rid of google play services, i just want to make it stop bothering for a few hours, but as soon i clear its data, it kicks in again after some seconds, making it impossible to use some good apps and games that are memory hungry. So, i just wanted  a button to suspend it, like we can do with netguard and most other apps that have a service.

@VeganEye Have you considered that the games trigger PlayServices for querying your Google Play subscriptions, performing Play Integrity check and so on?
